# How to remove github extension from Jupyterlab

Tags: python, github, jupyter-lab

Yesterday I added an extension of github to Jupyterlab but it seems to make the notebook very slow. I uninstalled it but I still see the fork on the side of my notebook. Any suggestions on how to remove it?

[image]

As I mentioned, I tried to uninstall github through the extensions section of Jupyterlab. Yet there still is some functionality with the extension.

Update: clearing the cookies and cache within my browser solved the problem. It wasn't the extension

Comment: I do not see a jupyterlab-github extension, but jupyterlab-git extension. What exactly did you try?

Comment: My apologies--I used the jupyterlab-git extension, not "github" extension. But I believe the issue was that I needed to clear my cookies/cache within my browser since I noticed it was running slow while browsing and I never actually cleared it.

https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-git